# iOS Status Bar touch to return to App

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, statusbar

This is puzzling me, does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this? The blue glowing status bar as in the image as what the Facebook app does when launching FB Messenger

[image]

Sorry bout the huge image!!! Would be great if anyone could point me to the right direction

Comment: Does anyone know how to achieve this? After I add my view to UIWindow and I move rootViewController down, origin of content view changes and I can't see top 20px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a custom view that sits on top of the navigation bar with a custom stylised title: `Touch to return to facebook`.
The navigation bar has an action applied to it so that when the user taps the navigation bar, the following code is executed to open the desired application, in this case facebook.

It uses the iPhone url scheme, whereby you can open up an application on the device directly from your app if the user has the application installed.

like this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb:]];
//and instead of fb: if you'd want it to open your custom app, 
//you simply add your own scheme instead: like so myappscheme:
```

To set a scheme for your own app follow the following instructions taken [from this site](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

1. Defining your app's custom URL scheme is all done in the Info.plist file. Click on the last line in the file and then click the "+" sign off to the right to add a new line. Select URL Types for the new item. Once that's added, click the grey arrow next to "URL Types" to show "Item 0". Set your URL identifier to a unique string - something like com.yourcompany.yourappname.
2. After you've set the URL identifier, select that line and click the "+" sign again, and add a new item for URL Schemes. Then click the grey arrow next to "URL Schemes" to reveal "Item 0". Set the value for Item 0 to be your URL scheme name.

[image]

Comment: wow that's a new perspective to how i thought they were going about making it. so ur saying its most prob a custom view sitting behind the status bar and above the navigation bar. Thanks for sharing i'll look into that then! also, thanks for the detailed description on creating a custom URL scheme for the app!

Comment: Yep, thats the way. You're going to love it when youre able to switch between apps by using the `openURL:` method.

Comment: How do you detect if app was called from another app and not the user opened it from the home screen?

Comment: @GeorgeAsda I think there's an application method available in your `appDelegate` with information on how the application was opened in the nsdictionary.. check the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method

Comment: @Pavan I have searched the web for this but nothing stands out clearly. It must be my search that sucks...

Comment: Hi, sorry. I just had time to answer your question. It's the source application parameter of this method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. Here is a link for more information on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: