# Come back to app from an other app

Tags: ios, objective-c

**Hello,**

When we are phoning with us iphone and you left the call view to come back at springboard, we can come back to the call view with the status bar. (This picture can better explain : http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tmpB178_thumb.jpg)

Or, in the Facebook app when you go to the messenger Facebook app (not same app) we can touch status bar to comme back Facebook App too.

***I would like to know if it's possible to make it in my app ? And if it's possible, how I will proceed ? (Edit: I want co come back in my app from another app such Youtube.)***

**Thanks**

Comment: do you want to come back to your app, after ending the call? or do you want to come back to your app, from some other app?

Comment: I want co come back in my app from another app such Youtube.

Comment: you can do that if you own both the apps. You cannot do it with an app that you do not own (unless the other app implements a way to open your app back)

Comment: Ok, So how I can proceed if I own both app?

Comment: is this what you want? http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

Comment: @HMHero Yes It's that. But I don't know how to use status bar such a button

Comment: @Jopolaz I'm sure there are different ways to achieve that. I would say you can have a UIView that sit on top of main view and then add a tap gesture to it. It should be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you become familiar with how to open another app within your current app form following link:

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html

You can simply create a view that has tap gesture and use it as a button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

    UIView *tapToReturnButton = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 40)];
    tapToReturnButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                      action:@selector(tapToReturnButtonClicked)];
    [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tapToReturnButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    UILabel *tapToReturnLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 20)];
    tapToReturnLabel.text = @"Tap to return";
    tapToReturnLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    tapToReturnLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    tapToReturnLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ArialMT"
                                        size:14];

    [tapToReturnButton addSubview:tapToReturnLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:tapToReturnButton];
}


- (void)tapToReturnButtonClicked
{
    NSLog(@"Now you add your code that opens another app(URL) here");
}
```

Edited:

After I posted the code above I kind of realized that there will be no tap gesture on the status bar even though other bottom part (20 pixel) of tapToReturnButton has a click gesture. After I did some research, I think following link has the better solution on click gesture. I will probably use tapToReturnButton as placeholder to let users know where to touch though and remove UITapGestureRecognizer *tap.

[How to detect touches in status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753097/how-to-detect-touches-in-status-bar)

Again, I think there is multiple way to achieve your need but those links above will give you good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

URL schemes will allow you to launch an app from an another app.

Check the following links for more info:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW18

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50

here are some system supported URL schemes
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899

Comment: Thanks but how I can custom the status bar such in a call ?

Comment: I am assuming, Facebook just adds a custom UIView with a glowing effect. Touching that uiview, will call the url scheme you have coded.

Comment: there's a SO post with similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22927047/ios-status-bar-touch-to-return-to-app